# Is this divergent or convergent? $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I did root test, but then I got stuck. In the end I got infinity/infinity ... can someone please tell me the right answer?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}+1}$$

Comment: Can you show your work on finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: Hint: $n^n=e^{n\ln n}$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\left|\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}+1}\right|^{1/n}<\left(\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{(n^n)^{1/n}}{(e^{n^2})^{1/n}}=\frac{n}{e^n}\;,$$

and you should know that limit of $\frac{n}{e^n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Added:** Since the problem turns out to be carrying on from here, I’ll suggest two approaches. First, you can apply l’Hospital’s rule. Alternatively, if you know that

$$e^x=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\;,$$

you can observe that

$$e^n>1+n+\frac{n^2}2$$

for each positive integer $n$ and hence that

$$\frac{n}{e^n}<\frac{n}{1+n+n^2/2}<\frac{n}{n^2/2}=\frac2n\;.$$

Comment: That's actually where I got stuck.

Comment: @CaptainAwesomE: You can use l’Hospital’s rule. There are other ways as well, but that’s very straightforward. For instance, if you know that $e^x=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}$, you can observe that $e^n>1+n+\frac{n^2}2$ and hence that $$\frac{n}{e^n}<\frac{n}{1+n+n^2/2}<\frac{n}{n^2/2}=\frac2n\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things, note that $0 \le \dfrac{n^n}{e^{n^2}+1} \le \dfrac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}$.

Hence, if $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}$ converges, then so does $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^n}{e^{n^2}+1}$ by direct comparison.

Now, try using the root test on $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly it's bounded above by
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (ne^{-n})^n, $$
since $(a^n)^n=a^{n^2}$. Now, the bracket has largest value at $n=1$ (easy to see by differentiation, for example), and this value is $e^{-1}$. Hence the whole sum is bounded above by
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-n} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}, $$
so it converges. And that's not anywhere near the best bound.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}{n^{n}}\frac{e^{n^{2}}+1}{e^{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}+1}\rightarrow0
 $$ as $n\rightarrow\infty
 $.